# How to get arraylist from activities and join them in fragment for filtering

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to get data from two activity class and join them for fragment search filter.

In CoinActivity and CoinActiviy2 class, I've such data

```
public ArrayList<Coin> getOnecoin()

    {
        ArrayList<Coin> coins = new ArrayList<>();

        Coin coadd = new Coin();

        coadd.setCoinid("0008");
        coadd.setCoinimages(R.drawable.noimage);
        coadd.setDenom("1");
        coadd.setYear("1701");
        coadd.setMints(this.getResources().getString(R.string.modelmint));
        coadd.setMarks("n/a");
        coadd.setVariety(this.getResources().getString(R.string.var1));
        coadd.setMintages("n/a");
        coadd.setObverses(this.getResources().getString(R.string.bust1));
        coins.add(coadd);

    return coins;
    }
```

I try in the fragment to join them by this code but when I use getAll() in search filter it comes with an error. The app does not open.

```
public ArrayList<Coin> getAll(){
        ArrayList<Coin> list = new ArrayList<>();
        CoinActivity yourObject = new CoinActivity();
        CoinActivity2 anotherObject = new CoinActivity2();
        list.addAll(yourObject.getOnecoin());
        list.addAll(anotherObject.getTwocoin());
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: app does not opening.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your logcat?

Comment: No errors in log. Just when app starts popups error massage and app closes.

Comment: I think in getall() it cant take data from .class files.

Comment: have you declared getTwocoin() method?

Comment: yes i have big data, i cant take it to fragment and because of it wont to take data from .class files and join them.

Comment: If you have big data, then you need to do your operation inside a separate thread than the main application thread.

Comment: because of big data it does not work? (i build data with arraylist i didnt use sqllite)

Comment: Pleas check your logs - it is highly unlikely that the app will crash and there is no stacktrace in the log. Check again. Also, why are you creating instances of CoinActivity and CoinActivity2? This is not something you do in Android and is probably the root of your problem.